# How to show all results of test (success and failure asserts) in report using nightwatch?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, functional-testing, nightwatch.js

I’m using Nightwatch for automated testing (E2E)

```
"nightwatch": "0.9.8"
"grunt-nightwatch": "0.5.4"
"grunt-nightwatch-report": "0.1.6"
```

I run my tests from jenkin.
How to show all results of test (success and failure asserts) in report?

Comment: have you followed this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-nightwatch-report ?

Comment: yes i followed but it shows me only the failure asserts

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib :

```
npm install nightwatch-html-reporter
```

Usage :

```
nightwatch-html-reporter -d <your report dictory>
```

Example:

```
nightwatch-html-reporter -d ~/myproject/reports
```

It will generate a html report(passed/failed/skipped test)

Comment: nightwatch-html-reporter he not show me messages of past and failure assert (ie not detailed), exactly what i want to do is to display a report that contains all results like when i run the test in the console.

Comment: @Asna Were you able to solve this ? I'm getting the same reports as you without details on test steps

Answer (score 0):

Use this in globals.js

```
const reporter = new HtmlReporter({
      openBrowser: false,
      separateReportPerSuite: false,
      uniqueFilename: true,
      reportsDirectory: `${__dirname }../../../reports`,
      reportFilename: "generatedReport.html"
    });

module.exports = {
  reporter: reporter.fn
};
```